# WPF DataTemplate and columns definition

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datatemplate

I need to improve the render of my grid. I have a template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ubitTemplateService" DataType="{x:Type data:uBit}">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="grdBit">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MAMC" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="ID" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="lblVIS" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding FIELD_Mac, Mode=OneWay}" Style="{StaticResource labelStyle1}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource txtBlockStyle2}" />
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Show.Caption}" Style="{StaticResource labelStyle4}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Basically for each record of my collection, a grid is rendered but as I have 300 or more record, the whole render takes about 2-3 seconds (each template was rendered into a Listbox)
I would want to change the layout and use a datagrid as follows:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="gridDati" BorderBrush="#abadb3" CanUserSortColumns="true" Margin="8,7,5,8">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource DataTemplateSelector}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

and I would want to use a datatemplate in order to render the columns, which may changes base on my datatype. The template selector is:

```
<local:DataconfigTemplateSelector ubitTemplateAv="{StaticResource ubitTemplateAv}" x:Key="DataTemplateSelector" />
```

The problem is that I want to put into my datatemplate the definition of DataGrid columns, for example a DataGridTextColumn:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ubitTemplateAv">
        <StackPanel>
            ...
        </StackPanel>                
    </DataTemplate>
```

How can I put into my datatemplate the columns definition like?

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" Header="Nome" Foreground="Black" IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="colName">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,7,4,6" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>           
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SurName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" Header="SurName" Foreground="Black" IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="colSurName">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,7,4,6" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the key is to use `DataGridTemplateColumn` instead of `DataGridTextColumn`.
Then you can do this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn
    Width="80">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Foo}" Padding="4,7,4,6"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Where should I put the DataGridTemplateColumn ? because I would need to use inside the <DataTemplate

Comment: Put it inside the `<DataGrid.Columns>`

Comment: This means that I do not have to use the <DataTemplate> with columns customisation? because that was my initial task

Comment: Well, you do use the `DataTemplate`, but the `DataTemplate` is placed within the `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate`. So it's the other way around than what you originally thought it would be. Looking again at the second block of code in your question, you already did this. The you've used the `CellTemplateSelector` for choosing the correct template based on the data, that's the way to do it. Was that not working?